# maven: pom.xml + compile + exec in windows dos-shell

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am using:

- java version "1.7.0_45"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

It's my first try to use maven - it seems to be very complicated :(

I want to use
https://github.com/squld/jircd

but the pom (see url and headline "maven repository") doesn't work (after using "mvn compile").
so i tried to create a pom.xml - here it is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>jircd</groupId>
<artifactId>jircd</artifactId>
<name>jircd</name>
<version>0.7.0-BETA</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>website</id>
        <url>scp://webhost.company.com/www/website</url>
    </site>
    <repository>
        <id>jp.kurusugawa.jircd</id>
        <name>jircd github repository</name>
        <url>file:./repository</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <name>squld</name>
        <url>http://kurusugawa.jp/author/squld/</url>
        <email>squld@kurusugawa.jp</email>
    </developer>
</developers>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<modules>
    <module>jircd-server</module>
    <module>jircd-servlet</module>
    <module>jircd-groovy</module>
</modules>
</project>
```

Well, "mvn compile" is successful.
The next step is to "execute" the jar-files like jircd-server-0.7.0-BETA.jar.

I tried to start it with "mvn exec:java".
The following errors occur:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project jircd: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException
```

My questions:
Is "mvn exec:java" the right way you execute it (in the windows DOS-shell; I do not use eclipse or something like that - batch-files are okay for me :) )?
How can I add the missing "mainClass" in the pom.xml? I tried but it doesn't work.
Maybe someone can post the correct pom.xml - would be great.

Comment: Read error carefully because it seams you don't understand it at the moment Then proceed to get full log as error message specifies and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

you have no any plugins that exec your compiled result. add this code in the `<build><plugins>  </plugins></build> block;`

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

notice that the com.example.Main is your Main class,then

```
mvn clean
mvn compile
mvn exec:java
```

just try it

Comment: tnx StackBox for your answer  
which name is the correct Main class?  
i tried:  
- jircd.jIRCd  
- jircd.jIRCd.Main  
- jircd.jIRCd.main  
... and some others :(  
  
hope you can help me again

Comment: The executed class means that the class consists of the `public static void main(String[] args)~, the main class name depends on you ,if your main class file named ~HelloWord.java~ and it's in package ~com.yourdomain.test~, then the name is ~com.yourdomain.test.HelloWord~, may it help you :)

Comment: https://github.com/squld/jircd ... the main class file is ~jIRCd.java~ and package ~jircd~ (because "package jircd;").
=> the main class would be ~jircd.JIRCd~, isn't it? but i tried it :(

Comment: notice that this repo has three different types module, the **dirct-server** is a normal java project, the **jirct-servlet** is a webapp project, i guess that you want to execute the first one , so  enter dirct-server dictonary, and replace the pom.xml with ()[https://gist.github.com/superalsrk/8368848](https://gist.github.com/superalsrk/8368848),  edit the jircd.properties depends on the mannual, and i succeed on with the maven commands below.

Comment: in my version i didnt have "<argument>jircd.properties</argument>" ;(
you're right some changes to make for the properties - but in general: it works :) tnx you VERY much - i think i would never solved this problem without your help